# How to model an owner and members with a has_many :through association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, has-many-through

In my rails application I have Event and User models. The business rules dictate that an Event has one owner and many members, and the owner must be a member. The inverse would be User having many 'owned events' and 'events' (events he/she is a member of but not the owner). I had originally planned to model this association like so:

```ruby
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_members, dependent: :destroy

  has_one :owner, through: :event_members, source: :user, conditions: { owner: true }
  has_many :members, through: :event_members, source: :user
end

class EventMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :owned_events, through: :event_members, conditions: { owner: true }
  has_many :events, through: :event_members
end
```

I thought that this would ensure one owner and that owner would be included in the members association for free. However, this doesn't work since I can't specify a has_one through a collection - the :event_members association.

Is there a better way to model this? I could add a transient 'owner' attr on Event that queries EventMember by the owner flag - but will that work for setting the owner (i.e. can I grab the EventMember record that is created and make sure the owner flag is set)?

Answer (score 4):

What about adding an `owner` attribute on the join model `EventMember` (also a field of type boolean in the `event_members` table, with default value of `false`). Access the `owner` and `owned_events` with methods on each respective model.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base             
  has_many :event_members
  has_many :members, :through => :event_members, :source => :user

  def owner                                  
    event_members.ownerships.map(&:user).first                                                              
  end                                        
end                                          

class EventMember < ActiveRecord::Base       
  belongs_to :event                          
  belogns_to :user

  scope :ownerships, -> { where(:owner => true) }                          
end                                          

class User < ActiveRecord::Base              
  has_many :event_members                    
  has_many :events, :through => :event_members

  def owned_events                           
    event_members.ownerships.map(&:event)      
  end                                        
end
```

The `Event` object may have the responsibility of making a user its owner.

```
class Event
  def make_owner!(user)
    membership = event_members.where(:user_id = user).first
    membership.owner = true
    membership.save
  end
end
```

Maybe place logic in there to enforce only one owner and abstract part of `make_owner!` to `EventMember` depending on how messy this gets in your application.

Comment: It looks like I'm going to have enforce ownership manually from the Event model some how. I've looked into these two solutions: [Association Extensions](http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/ruby/2012/04/03/use-association-extensions-to-build-join-attributes-on-a-hmt.html) and [Association gist](https://gist.github.com/sj26/2310315) - the latter getting me very close to what I want but I'm seeing odd behavior when accessing the `:through` attributes. I think your answer would require a `after_create` hook in case Event hasn't been saved in `make_owner!`